# how to create ul li dynamic menu with JSON

Tags: javascript, css, json, html

How to read a list from JSON and append as `li` in HTML?

`digikala.menu` is ul in JSON

```
request.onload = function () {
    var digikala = request.response;
    for (var i = 0; i < digikala.menu.length; i++) {
        var name = digikala.menu[0];
        var ul = document.getElementById("navigation_item");
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

Comment: `digikala.menu[0]` -> `digikala.menu[i]`

Comment: ul.appendChild(li);   can not read property

Comment: Show all related code

Comment: @Dani there is a simple mistake in forloop as commented by `ic3b3rg`

Comment: Still its not working then provide the HTML, Sample JSON!

Comment: here is working code:https://jsfiddle.net/2szfuw63/

Comment: probably your "menu" contain property and value so you have to use this :`digikala.menu[i].property` to get the value

Comment: Can you share what error you are facing if you can check browser console.

Comment: @Dani problem solved?

Comment: show the JSON that you want to iterate through.

Comment: @ Prashant Pimpale yes, tank you

Comment: @ לבני מלכה tank you very much